# Play in-memory MP3 Audio Stream in PowerShell, not from a file

Tags: powershell

I'd like to use PowerShell with Amazon Polly to play streaming audio, without writing the audio to disk first, on the Windows 10 platform. Amazon Polly APIs return a `System.IO.Stream` object, containing the raw MP3 audio. Normally, you could write this to disk by using a `System.IO.FileStream` object, however I'm interested in playing audio without the extra disk I/O.

**Question**: How do I play MP3 audio on Windows 10, directly from an in-memory stream?

#### Generate Speech Audio with Amazon Polly

```
$result = Get-POLSpeech -OutputFormat mp3 -Text 'Hello Trevor' -VoiceId Astrid
```

#### Inspect Properties on Result Object

```
$result | Get-Member -MemberType Property
```

#### Results From Above Command

```
   TypeName: Amazon.Polly.Model.SynthesizeSpeechResponse

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
AudioStream       Property   System.IO.Stream AudioStream {get;set;}
ContentLength     Property   long ContentLength {get;set;}
ContentType       Property   string ContentType {get;set;}
HttpStatusCode    Property   System.Net.HttpStatusCode HttpStatusCode {get;set;}
RequestCharacters Property   int RequestCharacters {get;set;}
ResponseMetadata  Property   Amazon.Runtime.ResponseMetadata ResponseMetadata {get;set;}
```

Comment: Powershell is not well suited to the task. If you use some inline c# its do-able. You will need to decode the mp3 stream using (something like) the lame mp3 codec - use a c# wrapper not the c++ library! Once you have a wav stream(all still in memory) then use the builtin SoundPlayer class to play wav the stream.